# What is a good workflow for submodule forks

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

Suppose we have the following repository structure on github:

```
company:project.git
  \- company:submodule.git
```

A developer in my company forks the company project, making his workspace look like this:

```
developer:project.git
  \- company:submodule.git
```

This is fine for 90% of the developers since they don't change the submodule library, they only work in the project. Now suppose there's a new feature which requires improvements in the submodule. The developer charged with this converts his workspace to this:

```
developer:project.git
   \- developer:submodule.git
```

Getting there is not trivial as he needs to replace a submdule with another submodule (to git, the original and the fork of the submodule are two different things).

If this developer works on the library for a bit longer, he commits this structure to his master branch, so his fork on github always uses the forked submodule.

Once he's ready with development, he'll create a pull request. The problem is that when merging the pull request the main repository will look like this:

```
company:project.git
   \- developer:submodule.git
```

This is problematic as now every developer that tracks the company branch will end up with the developer's submodule.

To workaround the problem, before the developer makes a pull request, his master branch should be moved back to the company:submodule.git - which is just very awkward, especially since locally he'll always still want to work with developer:submodule.git.

We've tried several workflows, and the above issue is the only one where we don't have a good workflow yet.

Comment: This a weird workflow. Why would you have forks in modules and not in branches?

Comment: branches and forks are 2 separate things. We use forks - the maintainer of a project pulls pull requests from the developer's forks. Pull requests are code reviewed. With forks, we only have to give readonly access to the main repositories, which is a great way to keep the main repository intact. The submodules are intended for code reuese, they comprise libraries (our own and third party libs) that are reused between projects.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I would put each project into a separate git repo (not a module), but I guess, that's just personal preference.

Comment: they are separate repositories. But they are added as a submodule to each other if there are dependencies. (e.g. projectX requires libY)

Comment: So why don't just track the head in the repo as a local branch?

Comment: Because the developer has no push privileges to the repo; to be able to commit their work to the repo there's a fork. But let me turn the question around, you seem to be against forking; is there any disadvantage to forking I'm not aware about?

Comment: I'm not against forking, I'm just used to tracking everything in my local repo. You don't need push privileges for that, only pull.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the developer creates a commit with the submodule at a particular version, that's a strong statement that the supermodule works with the submodule at that exact version.  If his code does actually work with the company's version of the submodule, I think the right thing to do is for the developer to:

1. branch the supermodule
2. checkout the company version in the submodule
3. update `.gitmodules` in the supermodule, if the developer changed that from the upstream version
4. stage and commit that change
5. test everything
6. issue the pull request

He can then switch back to his normal development branch in the supermodule.

One thing I don't understand about your question is the following:

> Getting there is not trivial as he needs to replace a submdule with another submodule (to git, the original and the fork of the submodule are two different things).

On the contrary, the submodule can be any git repository so long as it contains the commit which the supermodule points to.  If there are two different remote repositories, he can just add an extra remote in the submodule.  (The developer should change `.gitmodules` as well if they're going to share their repository with anyone else.)

---

In response to your comment below, perhaps it's worth going through how to switch a submodule from pointing to one version to another.  Let's suppose that the developer is using their own repositories for the super and submodule, but those are both cloned from the company's versions (i.e. so most of the history is the same), and the submodule is at the path `lib`.  The developer now wants to switch the submodule to point to the company's version instead.  They can do the following:

1. Edit the `url` parameter for the submodule in `.gitmodules` to point to the company's repository.
2. `cd lib`
3. `git remote add company developer@company:/srv/git/lib.git`
4. `git fetch company`
5. `git checkout -b upstream-master company/master`
6. `cd ..`
7. `git add .gitmodules lib`
8. `git commit -m "Switch the lib submodule to point back to the company's version"`

Steps 3 to 5 can just be changed to `git checkout <whatever>` once the remote and branch are set up.

Comment: If you simply change .gitmodules git will be confused. Switching between the forks requires removing the source, changing .gitmodules to remove the old fork, committing, adding the other fork as a submodule, committing again - that's what I meant with non-trivial.

Comment: No, `.gitmodules` only has effect when you are first initializing a submodule.  Once it's initialized and updated you can do whatever you like to the submodule as if it were an independent repository without touching `.gitmodules`.

Comment: Of course, if the developer is allowing other people to clone his version, `.gitmodules` should contain a pointer to the repository that contains the commit in the submodule.  However, you certainly don't need to remove the submodule and replace it to do that.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of how to change the repository that the submodule points at and the commit that it's at.  I've also changed the wording of what I said about `.gitmodules` a little, since usually people will want to change that too.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer; I will give this process a try; if it works, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @IvoJansch the answer is still not accepted... has it not worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

Another, simple solution is to tell git to ignore .gitmodules and to remove them from tracking. As said above, .gitmodules are used only for initializing submodules, so it's needed only once, upon checking out the submodules.

Comment: That is interesting ".gitmodules are used only for initializing submodules".  I guess you're right, but I'd be 9/10 people don't realize/register that fact.  It is definitely relevant to this use-case.

Answer (score 2):

For him to develop on it, the dev doesn't need to change the submodule itself - they could add another remote and push to it.

Example:

```
developer:project.git
  \- company:submodule.git
        Origins: company/submodule.git
                 developer/submodule.git
```

Workflow:

```
cd path/to/submodule
git remote add developer git@gitserver/developer/submodule.git
```

// hack on the project

```
cd path/to/submodule
git push developer branchname
```

It's definitely not perfect and may cause issues if a pull request on developer/project makes it in to company/project before developer/submodule makes it in to company/submodule.

Just my quick thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

> Now suppose there's a new feature which requires improvements in the submodule.

Contribution being made in submodule, only commits in submodule git repo are to be pull requested, as usual.

In order to push on your submodule fork,

- project .gitmodules config can be changed in your cloned fork (but is kept on your side)
- or your submodule fork can be added as a remote